Some endpoints in ASP.NET Core 8.0 OpenAPI Swagger don't have authentication
I'm developing an ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API. Could you tell me why some endpoints don't have a padlock icon in Swagger UI?
For example, my ASP.NET localhost: localhost ASP.NET swagger.
On the other hand, preview at editor.swagger.io is correct: editor.swagger.io preview.
When I'm executing request (e.g. to /authorize path), request header hasn't Authentication field.
Second problem, in my opinion related to first one, is that after click on the padlock, I get all authentication options.
For example, I click on GET /student endpoint and I'll get this: all options authorizations at localhost. In the editor.swagger.io I'll get one, proper option: one option authorization at editor.swagger.io.
That's my openapi.yaml:
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: API schema for research project
  description: API schema for research project
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
  - url: 'localhost'
tags:
  - name: general
  - name: student
    description: Access to student data.
paths:
  /hello:
    get:
      tags:
        - general
      summary: Returns "Hello World!" phrase
      description: Returns "Hello World!" phrase.
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
          content:
            text/plain:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/HelloWorld'
  /authorize:
    post:
      tags:
        - general
      summary: Get authorization JWT token
      description: Returns JWT token for further authorization.
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
          content:
            text/plain:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/JwtToken'
        '401':
          description: unauthorized
      security:
        - jwt_token_auth: []
  /student:
    get:
      tags:
        - student
      summary: Find first n students
      description: Find and return first n students ordered by its IDs.
      parameters:
        - name: results
          in: query
          description: Number of students to return.
          schema:
            type: integer
            default: 1
            minimum: 1
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Student'
        '400':
          description: Invalid 'results' parameter value
        '401':
          description: unauthorized
      security:
        - student_data_auth: []
    post:
      tags:
        - student
      summary: Add a new students
      description: Add a new students
      requestBody:
        description: Create a new students
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: array
              items:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Student'
        required: true
      responses:
        '201':
          description: Created successfully
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Student'
        '400':
          description: Invalid input
        '401':
          description: unauthorized
        '422':
          description: Validation exception
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/ErrorMessage'
      security:
        - student_data_auth: []
  /student/{studentId}:
    put:
      tags:
        - student
      summary: Update student
      description: Update student by given ID.
      parameters:
        - name: studentId
          in: path
          description: ID of the student to update
          required: true
          schema:
            type: integer
      requestBody:
        description: Update existing student
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Student'
        required: true
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Updated successfully
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Student'
        '400':
          description: Invalid input
        '401':
          description: unauthorized
        '404':
          description: Student not found
        '422':
          description: Validation exception
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/ErrorMessage'
      security:
        - student_data_auth: []
    patch:
      tags:
        - student
      summary: Update some fields of student
      description: Update some fields of student by given student ID.
      parameters:
        - name: studentId
          in: path
          description: ID of the student to update
          required: true
          schema:
            type: integer
      requestBody:
        description: Update existing student
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Student'
        required: true
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Updated successfully
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Student'
        '400':
          description: Invalid input
        '401':
          description: unauthorized
        '404':
          description: Student not found
        '422':
          description: Validation exception
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/ErrorMessage'
      security:
        - student_data_auth: []
    delete:
      tags:
        - student
      summary: Delete student by ID
      description: Delete student by given ID.
      parameters:
        - name: studentId
          in: path
          description: ID of the student to delete
          required: true
          schema:
            type: integer
      responses:
        '204':
          description: Deleted successfully
        '401':
          description: unauthorized
        '404':
          description: Student not found
      security:
        - student_data_auth: []
components:
  schemas:
    HelloWorld:
      type: string
      example: "Hello World!"
    JwtToken:
      type: string
      example: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c
    Student:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          readOnly: true
          example: 1
        gender:
          type: string
          maxLength: 10
          example: female
        title:
          type: string
          maxLength: 20
          example: Miss
        first_name:
          type: string
          maxLength: 50
          example: Terri
        last_name:
          type: string
          maxLength: 50
          example: Lucas
        email:
          type: string
          maxLength: 100
          example: terri.lucas@example.com
        dob:
          type: string
          description: date of birth
          format: date
          example: 1964-11-23
        registered:
          type: string
          description: date of registration
          format: date-time
          example: 2014-07-23T03:21:42.259Z
        phone:
          type: string
          maxLength: 20
          example: 03-2662-3559
        id_name:
          type: string
          maxLength: 20
          description: national identification number type
          example: TFN
        id_value:
          type: string
          maxLength: 50
          description: national identification number value
          example: '230000682'
        nat:
          type: string
          maxLength: 10
          description: nationality short code
          example: AU
        location:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Location'
        picture:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Picture'
    Location:
      type: object
      properties:
        street_number:
          type: integer
          example: 2595
        street_name:
          type: string
          maxLength: 100
          example: Main Street
        city:
          type: string
          maxLength: 100
          example: Tamworth
        state:
          type: string
          maxLength: 100
          example: Queensland
        country:
          type: string
          maxLength: 100
          example: Australia
        postcode:
          type: string
          maxLength: 20
          example: '6066'
        timezone:
          type: string
          maxLength: 10
          example: +5:30
    Picture:
      type: object
      properties:
        large:
          type: string
          maxLength: 255
          example: https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/75.jpg
        medium:
          type: string
          maxLength: 255
          example: https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/75.jpg
        thumbnail:
          type: string
          maxLength: 255
          example: https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/75.jpg
    ErrorMessage:
      type: object
      properties:
        field:
          type: string
          example: first_name
        message:
          type: string
          example: Input must be string
  securitySchemes:
    jwt_token_auth:
      type: http
      scheme: basic
    student_data_auth:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT

I'll just add that my ASP.NET Core code was generated by OpenAPI generator in IntelliJ. After that I hadn't any authorization, and after added OpenApiSecurityRequirement I got above situation.

Update:
AuthController.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;

namespace StudentApi.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("Auth")]
    public class AuthController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost("authorize")]
        [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Basic")]
        public IActionResult Authorize()
        {
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(""); // Make sure this is consistent
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, User.Identity.Name)
        }),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
                Issuer = "https://localhost:7013", // Ensure issuer matches
                Audience = "https://localhost:7013/api", // Ensure audience matches
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };
            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
            return Ok(tokenString);
        }

    }

}

StudentController.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using StudentApi.Models;

namespace StudentApi.Controllers
{
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("Student")]
    public class StudentController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly List<Student> Students = new List<Student>
        {
            new Student { Id = 1, FirstName = "Terri", LastName = "Lucas", Email = "terri.lucas@example.com" }
        };

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Student>> GetStudents(int results = 1)
        {
            return Ok(Students.Take(results));
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Student>> AddStudent([FromBody] List<Student> newStudents)
        {
            Students.AddRange(newStudents);
            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetStudents), newStudents);
        }

        [HttpPut("{studentId}")]
        public ActionResult<Student> UpdateStudent(int studentId, [FromBody] Student updatedStudent)
        {
            var student = Students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == studentId);
            if (student == null)
                return NotFound();

            student.FirstName = updatedStudent.FirstName;
            student.LastName = updatedStudent.LastName;
            student.Email = updatedStudent.Email;
            return Ok(student);
        }

        [HttpPatch("{studentId}")]
        public ActionResult<Student> PatchStudent(int studentId, [FromBody] Student updatedFields)
        {
            var student = Students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == studentId);
            if (student == null)
                return NotFound();

            if (updatedFields.FirstName != null)
                student.FirstName = updatedFields.FirstName;

            if (updatedFields.LastName != null)
                student.LastName = updatedFields.LastName;

            if (updatedFields.Email != null)
                student.Email = updatedFields.Email;

            return Ok(student);
        }

        [HttpDelete("{studentId}")]
        public IActionResult DeleteStudent(int studentId)
        {
            var student = Students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == studentId);
            if (student == null)
                return NotFound();

            Students.Remove(student);
            return NoContent();
        }
    }

}

BasicAuthenticationHandler.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace StudentApi.Handlers
{
    public class BasicAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
    {
        public BasicAuthenticationHandler(
            IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
            ILoggerFactory logger,
            UrlEncoder encoder,
            ISystemClock clock)
            : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
        {
        }

        protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            if (!Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
            {
                return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Missing Authorization Header"));
            }

            try
            {
                var authHeader = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(Request.Headers["Authorization"]);
                var credentialBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(authHeader.Parameter);
                var credentials = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(credentialBytes).Split(':');
                var username = credentials[0];
                var password = credentials[1];

                // Validate credentials here
                if (username == "{username}" && password == "{password}") // Replace with your own validation logic
                {
                    var claims = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username) };
                    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Scheme.Name);
                    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name);

                    return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
                }
                else
                {
                    return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid Username or Password"));
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid Authorization Header"));
            }
        }
    }
}

Program.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;

namespace StudentApi.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("Auth")]
    public class AuthController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost("authorize")]
        [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Basic")]
        public IActionResult Authorize()
        {
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(""); // Make sure this is consistent
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, User.Identity.Name)
        }),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
                Issuer = "https://localhost:7013", // Ensure issuer matches
                Audience = "https://localhost:7013/api", // Ensure audience matches
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };
            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
            return Ok(tokenString);
        }

    }

}




Well, my idea isn't quite like that. student_data_auth is for student endpoints authorization. At the other hand, jwt_token_auth is for \authorize endpoint only. I want to pass login and password to this endpoint and get JWT token for student endpoint group.

@MAtt could you check if the updated code will work for you. let me know if you still have any concern
